# Conftest Policy for Kubernetes manifests for checking that images come from a specific registry

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rego, conftest

I'm using [conftest](https://www.conftest.dev/) for validating policies on Kubernetes manifests.

Below policy validates that images in StatefulSet manifests have to come from specific registry `reg_url`

```
package main

deny[msg] {
  input.kind == "StatefulSet"
  not regex.match("[reg_url]/.+", input.spec.template.spec.initContainers[0].image)

  msg := "images come from artifactory"
}
```

Is there a way to enforce such policy for all kubernetes resources that have image field somewhere in their description? This may be useful for policy validation on all `helm` chart manifests, for instance.

I'm looking for something like:

```
package main

deny[msg] {
  input.kind == "*" // all resources
  not regex.match("[reg_url]/.+", input.*.image) // any nested image field

  msg := "images come from artifactory"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this using something like the [walk](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#builtin-graph-walk) built-in function. However, I would recommend against it, because:

- You'd need to scan every attribute of every request/resource (expensive).
- You can't know for sure that e.g. "image" means the same thing across all current and future resouce manifests, including CRDs.

I'd probably just stick with checking for a match of resource kind here, and include any resource type known to have an image attribute with a shared meaning.